# pySerial: opening multiple ports at once

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

**EDIT**: Found the problem: I tried referencing a variable, but mixed up its name, so instead I declared a new variable.  Turns out pySerial is not limited to one open serial point at a time.

I'm trying to open two serial ports at once using the following code

```
    ser0 = serial.Serial(
                         port = port_list[0],
                         baudrate = 115200,
                         timeout = 0.1
                         )

    ser1 = serial.Serial(
                         port = port_list[1],
                         baudrate = 115200,
                         timeout = 0.1
                         )
```

But it seems that I open the second, the first one closes.  Is there an inherent limit to one serial port open at a time using pySerial?

Thanks,
T.G.

EDIT: I should have posted this to begin with

```
while not (comm_port0_open and comm_port1_open):
    print 'COM ports available:'
    port_list = []
    i = 0
    for port in __EnumSerialPortsWin32():
        port_list.append(port[0])
        print '%i:' % i, port[0]
        i+=1
    print 'Connect to which port? (0, 1, 2, ...)'
    comm_port_str = sys.stdin.readline()
    try:
        if len(comm_port_str)>0:
            if comm_port0_open:
                ser1 = serial.Serial(
                                    port = port_list[int(comm_port_str)],
                                    baudrate = 115200,
                                    timeout = 0.1
                                    )
                comm1_port_open = True
                print '%s opened' % port_list[int(comm_port_str)]
            else:
                ser0 = serial.Serial(
                                    port = port_list[int(comm_port_str)],
                                    baudrate = 115200,
                                    timeout = 0.1
                                    )
                comm0_port_open = True
                print '%s opened' % port_list[int(comm_port_str)]                   
        else:
            print 'Empty input'
    except:
        print 'Failed to open comm port, try again'
```

Comment: What is the value of port_list? How do you know that the first port closes?

Comment: port_list[] contains ports enumerated using the _winreg module.  I am certain that I can successfully open one port.  I believe that opening a second port causes the first to close because the above code is actually nested in a loop (i.e. the code above is not quite in context) that runs until both ports are open.  In the loop, I open one port (let's say COM10).  If I try to re-open the same port, it fails (as it should).  If I attempt to open a second port, I can - but the loop continues.  Attempting to re-open the first port works, which leads me to believe it closes when I open the second.

Comment: Have you tried the long form, ie `\\.\COM10`, if they are outside the range COM1..COM9?

Comment: I haven't - port_list[int(comm_port_str)] evaluates to COM10, not \\.\COM10, but I don't think this is the problem because I can open one port on it's own without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the context of the code, this is only a guess.

Serial ports will be closed when they are garbage collected and [`__del__`](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.__del__) is run. Uner CPython, if your `ser0` reference count drops to zero after that block of code is run, but somehow the `ser1` doesn't, it will give the appearance of one port closing when the other opens.

But post more code!

Answer (score 0):

The variables referenced when declaring the com ports open do not match the ones checked in the while condition.  Oops.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you test `comm_port0_open` and `comm_port1_open`, but set them with `comm0_port_open = True` and `comm1_port_open`. Different names!

Another point: don't use bare 'except', it can hide all kinds of errors.