# pySerial - Is there a way to select on multiple ports at once?

Tags: python, windows

I am developing app that need to communicate  with many serial ports. I havnt found a way to do this without using thread per port. Is there a way to do this with single thread?something like select or poll on multiple ports at once? I am using pyserial 2.6

Comment: can help pySerial: opening multiple ports at once,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603475/pyserial-opening-multiple-ports-at-once

Comment: the problem is not opening them, but waiting on read events on them in parallel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using PySerial on a unix like platform...

Since [PySerial objects implement `fileno()`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.fileno) to get the underlying file descriptor, you can pass them straight into [`select()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select) which will allow you to do deal with multiple PySerial objects at once.

Another alternative would be to open the `Serial` object in non-blocking (read) mode (by passing `timeout=0`) and deal with the fact that your reads and writes may return `errno.EWOULDBLOCK` errors. This is probably the simplest method.

A third alternative would be to use [twisted serial ports](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.0.0/api/twisted.internet.serialport.BaseSerialPort.html) if you don't mind getting your head round the way twisted does things.

**Update**

For Windows, pretty much your only alternative other than using threads is to use the [`in_waiting` property](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.in_waiting).  Poll all your serial ports regularly reading `in_waiting` from them.  If there is stuff waiting then you can read that and only that many bytes without blocking.

Unfortunately pyserial doesn't have a "how much free space is there in the output buffer" method which means that when you write to serial ports you are at risk of blocking.  If you are implementing a typical serial port protocol the default buffer sizes of a few kilobytes will ensure that this isn't normally a problem.

Comment: Unfortunatly I need it under windows, so niether fileno() nor nonblocking() is available

Comment: Have added a section about Windows for you.  Suggest you write OS in the question next time as it is kind of important for something so platform dependent as serial ports!